# How to load spring data jpa's database configuration from a external file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

As we need to deploy a spring project on clients' servers, we cannot use application.properties to setup jpa's database configuration. Then the project needs to dynamically load the configuration from an external json file which locates in somewhere of the server(not in the war package). How to do this for spring data jpa configuration?

updated:
Loading external configuration from the spring cloud seems like a good idea.

Comment: Do you mean to have dynamic DB configuration for each environment?

Comment: Have you read the Spring Boot documentation regarding [externalizing properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)? Which explains that you can also have an `application.properties` outside of your app or pass arguments for configuration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a two step process.

Step 1 Read the configuration data from the json file.

Step 2 Create a Datasource configuration bean and set the values as read from the configuration file.

See the sample below

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {

    // This is your custom bean that read the json file  
    MyDataSource dataSource= MyDatasource.load("/path/to/json/file")
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(dataSource.getDriver());
    dataSourceBuilder.url(dataSource.getJDBCUrl());
    dataSourceBuilder.username(dataSource.getUsername());
    dataSourceBuilder.password(dataSource.getPassword());
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

}

Comment: Which beats the purpose of the configuration in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do it like that:

```
@Configuration
public class ExternalPropertyConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("config/application.properties"));
        properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

For deployment, create near to the .jar **config/application.properties**